# What program can I use to preview my wordpress site?

Tags: theme-development, previews, offline

Apologies if this is the wrong site to be asking this, but I just downloaded a template for a website that I want to customise. On my Mac I have a program called Espresso which allows me to 'preview' any website that contains any mix of client-side and server-side files. Is there an equivalent on the PC?

I essentially just want to preview my website offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install any program - for example [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/) - that allows you to use Apache and MySQL. Then go to [wordpress.org](https://www.wordpress.org/download) and download the [latest copy](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip) of WordPress. [Install it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) and upload your theme in the `wp-content/themes` folder.

Answer (score 0):

With respect, the up-voted answer will result in an unmitigated disaster.

It doesn't allow for plugins or uploads or other files that are a part of the website; it doesn't mention the need to edit the database options table; the possibility of editing the config.php file; etc, etc.

Rather than regurgitate the necessary steps, I would recommend one of the many guides to be found on the web. This one, "[How to Move a Live WordPress Site to Local Server (Manually)](https://www.thebrokebillion.com/move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/)" seems as good as any. It covers all the steps in detail, and has a linked article on building the local server (should that be needed).